# react router v6 and nest UI and URL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to figure out what this bit of code means:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route
      path="messages"
      element={<DashboardMessages />}
    />
    <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route

If the location is `/`, then the rendered UI will be

```
<Dashboard />
```

While if the location is `/messages`, then the rendered UI will be

```
<Dashboard >
  <DashboardMessages />
<Dashboard />
```

Same logic for `/tasks` and `/about`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is partly correct. Given the following routing code:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route path="messages" element={<DashboardMessages />} />
    <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```

It is correct that when the URL path is `"/"` that only the `Dashboard` component is rendered. This is what is called a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). Layout routes generally provide some common component lifecycle and/or common UI layout, i.e. headers and footers, navbars, sidebars, etc.

When the URL path is `"/messages"` or `"/tasks"` the `Dashboard` component is rendered *as well as* the specifically matched routed content `DashboardMessages` or `DashboardTasks` into an `Outlet` component rendered by `Dashboard`.

Note that the `"/about"` route is *outside* the `"/"` dashboard layout route. When the path is `"/about"` then *only* `AboutPage` is rendered.

Here's an example layout route components:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => {
  ... common logic ...

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element here
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

const NavbarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element here
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
    ... routes w/ header/footer & w/o navbar

    <Route element={<NavbarLayout />}>
      ... routes also w/ navbar
    </Route>

    ...
  </Route>

  ... routes w/o header/footer
</Routes>
```